# Configurable Joint, linear limit range

Tags: unity, physics, 3d, joints

I am working on a physics driven pressable button, but I cannot seem to tackle the minimum and maximum limits.

This is the *rig* I have set up for the button (as it looks when pressed down).
2D view:
[image: 2D view]

3D view:
[image: 3D view]

The idea is that the box collider is a trigger and the button (cylinder, mesh collider) is a rigidbody with configurable joint, locked and limited on a single axis. I am using configurable joint, as that's the only one that supports basic, linear restrictions.

I have set up the configurable joint to restrict motion on a single axis, but the joint only allows single dimensional limit, that is applied to both directions. Screen capture of relevant configuration:
[image: Configuration Joint configuration]

Basically, the opened `Linear Limit` section is the last property that has been changed for the joint - anything else are defaults and irrelevant (at least I haven't found my solution in the properties below, mostly angular stuff).

The limit of `0.2` units work, and the button can be pressed - it only gets *pressed* until those `0.2` units and thats the expected behaviour.
The unexpected is that sometimes the angle at which I hit the button, adds force to the button outwards from the box, and it moves `0.2` away from it, ending up like this:

[image: The unexpected upper limit]

Obviously, the specified limit of `0.2` units constrain the movement in both directions from the anchor, actually resulting in the range of `-0.2` to `0.2` (relative to anchor).

How, and is it even possible, to restrict the movement only in a single direction relative to anchor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about the fact that the limit isn't a min-max limit, but rather constraints in both directions. So if your goal is to limit your movement range to `0.2` units, your limit has to be set to `0.1` (`-0.1 - 0.1`).

For this to work correctly, your initial "button" position has to be centered between the desired min- and max-position.

You can then add an initial force to move the button to its max position or add a `Constant Force` Component to the button which will push the button outwards. The latter will have the nice effect that the button will move back out once pressed.

Comment: Oh, the Constant Force idea is awesome, though, not always desired. Initial force... is it a Configurable Joint property or should I add a script that will _hit_ the button upon `Start()`?

Comment: @joltmode It's not a property, you'd have to add a script that moves the button to the desired position in `Start`.